# Error screen in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Why I have error screen like this:
[image]

Not like this:
[image]

Comment: Because you don't have [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) installed (or at least not active), this comes by default with the newer laravel versions.

Comment: you are using older version of laravel

Comment: I have version 5.3.31

Comment: whoops is available in laravel 5.5 and 5.6. 5.3 does'nt have whoops installed by default

Comment: Understood. Thanks)